# R caret high instance training

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, bigdata

I have a dataset that I need to analyze in R with some ML algorithm.
Here is my code:

```
#data is a big db (351444 obj and 39 variables). It contains physiological data about different users. 
library('mlbench')
library('randomForest')
library('nnet')
library("kernlab")
library('caret')
library('rpart')
library('caretEnsemble')
library('pROC')
data$target <- as.factor(emodata$target) #i need to do a classification

set.seed(12)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$target, p = .8,
                                  list = FALSE,
                                  times = 1)
Train <- data[ trainIndex,]
Test  <- data[-trainIndex,]

my_control <- trainControl(
  method='cv',
  number=5,
  savePredictions=TRUE,
  classProbs=TRUE,
  verboseIter=TRUE,
  allowParallel=TRUE,
  index=createResample(Train$target),
  summaryFunction=twoClassSummary
)

model_list <- caretList(
  target~., data=Train,
  trControl=my_control,
  metric='ROC',
  # methodList=c('glm', 'rpart'),
  tuneList=list(
    svmLinear=caretModelSpec(method='svmLinear',tuneGrid=expand.grid(.C=c(0.01,0.1,1,3,5,10,20))),
    svmPoly=caretModelSpec(method='svmPoly',tuneGrid=expand.grid(.degree=(2:5), .scale=.1, .C=c(0.01,0.1,1,3,5,10,20))),
    svmRadial=caretModelSpec(method='svmRadial',tuneGrid=expand.grid(.sigma=.1,.C=c(0.01,0.1,1,3,5,10,20))),
    rf=caretModelSpec(method='rf'),
    nn=caretModelSpec(method='nnet',tuneGrid=expand.grid(.size=(1:15),.decay=c(0.01,0.1,1,3,5,10,20)))
  )
)
```

When I launch this code everything seems to work fine. Anyway, after some time, model_list code return error of memory allocation:

```
    Resample01: C= 0.01 
model fit failed for Resample01: C= 0.01 Error : cannot allocate vector of size 427.1 Gb

- Resample01: C= 0.01 
+ Resample01: C= 0.10 
model fit failed for Resample01: C= 0.10 Error : cannot allocate vector of size 427.1 Gb
```

A little 'I expected this error. However, I do not know how to solve it. I have no idea about how to reduce the lines (they are user's physiological measurements).

Can you help me?

Regards

Comment: I am wondering how a  ~ [350,000 x 39] data frame can become 427 GB. Or do I misinterpret the Error?

Comment: Have you tried to run the different methods  seperatly in order to localize more exactly where the error comes from?  And is your code complete? Where does `caretList()` comes from. I cannot find this function in the `caret` package.

Comment: @alex, yep. The error is correct. caretList() is a method of caretensamble. It is the same of using the different models. The error become on the first of the list: SVM with linear kernel.

Comment: You should add all loaded packages to your code. Furthermore, it will be hard too help without having the data. I would first try to perform the tuning on a smaller subset of your data and also to change some of the parameters (for what do you need `verboseIter = TRUE`?).  And I would do that for only one method. Debugging won't be fun if the error only turns up after 2 hours.

Comment: You also might try using `svmLinear2` or `svmLinear3` instead.

Comment: @alex I added all packages! 'verboseIter=TRUE' print every interaction. With a small dataset (1% of mine) works. Anyway it try to resample and is consuming a lot of time.

Comment: @topepo There is a documentation about these?